# Video Editing Books

Tags: image-processing

Could you recommend me some book on algorithms about video editing? I would like to understand the principals algorithms of image manipulation. This is not for a commercial project, is only for learn. I don't want to learn some graphics library, I want to learn the algorithms of image manipulation

Comment: By video editing, do you mean use of the different softwares and how they work? or do you mean about how the actual algorithms used to complete the process are written?

Comment: I mean the actual algorithms used to complete the process

Comment: Learning opencv is a good book.

Comment: your question is too general.  video editing, image manipulation are two different things.  what exactly are you interested in?  you say you don't want to learn "some graphics library", but it's hard to learn about image processing without at least some exposure to at least one toolkit (e.g. opencv as suggested above).  Also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image+processing+book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't really any algorithms for video editing - you just store all the footage, index it and display it.

There is a lot to learn about color spaces, how to convert between them, adjusting colors, brightnesses etc.

[image]
 [http://www.amazon.com/Video-Demystified-Handbook-Digital-Engineer/dp/0750683953/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1295232023&sr=1-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750683953)

Most of the algorithm bit is in compression, most compression schemes are based on the ideas in JPEG so any background on that might be usefull. There are a few print versions with comments on the H264 standard but I don't know any of them.