# I want to learn DirectShow & MediaFoundation programming right from basics. Help needed on learning resources (Website links, etc..)

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, com, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I want to learn DirectShow & MediaFoundation programming right from basics. Help needed on training resources (Website links, etc..).

What all prerequisites should one have to start with DirectShow & MF programming.

I think I must have COM programming basics for this. Since I need to quickly ramp up with  DirectShow & MF, it would be very helpful if one can kindly let me know which part of COM should I know to do with DShow & MF programming. (As I don't have much time, I need to quickly do with COM so that I can spare more time ramping up DirectShow & MF).

Helping me with Training links on COM would also be very helpful.

I am a fresher to COM,MFC, DirectShow,Media foundation etc..... (Training links provided keeping this in mind would very helpful to ramp up from basics)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good book for getting started with Media Foundation http://www.docstoc.com/docs/109589628/Developing-Microsoft-Media-Foundation-Applications#.

Answer (score 1):

Multimedia API have not been drawing sufficient attention to result in books. There are no good resources for MF that I am aware of due to limited interest to Media Foundation, and a good book for DirectShow is the question brought up many times over years - you will find answers [DirectShow introduction material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121713/directshow-introduction-presentations) and in other topics and sites. Additionally, you will perhaps want to get some basic introduction into digital video/audio such as with a book mentioned here [Video Editing Books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708989/video-editing-books)